# URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?) when deploying HEROKU app with multiple databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, multiple-databases

Im trying to deploy a heroku app with multiple databases (2 at the moment). I was following this tutorial

[Multiple database guide](http://www.ostinelli.net/setting-multiple-databases-rails-definitive-guide/)

that said that I need to configure a file like this

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  url:  <%= ENV["DATABASE_DAVILA_URL"] %>
  pool: <%= ENV["DB_POOL"] || 5 %>
```

The problem is when im trying to deploy to heroku, this error happens

```
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): <%= ENV["DATABASE_DAVILA_URL"] %>
```

It's like is not parsing the link correctly because I even tried to hardcode the URI in the variable and didn't work. Here is the important part of the env vars:

```
DATABASE_DAVILA_URL:         postgres://somethinguser:somethingpass@somethinghost.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/somethingdb
DATABASE_URL:                postgres://somethinguser:somethingpass@somethinghost.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/somethingdb
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAUVE_URL: postgres://somethinguser:somethingpass@somethinghost.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/somethingdb
```

I followed almost every tutorial that I've found, but I keep getting the same error. I even tried something I read like "not loading the env vars in the precompiling phase" with this code, but didn't change anything

```
module Indicadoresrails
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.load_defaults 5.2

    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
  end
end
```

Please help :(

Comment: Did you run the `heroku config:set` command to set those env vars?

Comment: Yes I did. After that I got the env vars values I posted

Comment: You might want to change those credentials :-O

Comment: Are the database URLs your real production configuration settings? If that is the case you should change the password immediately. And if there is already data in that databases you might need to inform your data protection officer.

Comment: Those are just dummy data, a copy of an old DB, nothing important.

Comment: Have you tried placing the URIs in quotes in the yaml file? I have had issues with certain characters breaking yaml in the past.

Comment: Tried with and without quotes in the yaml and in the config vars of heroku, no one worked. Also tried again hardcoding the URI and now it works but won’t work for too long as heroku rotates the credentials. It’s like is not properly reading the ENV VAR. I’ve tried changing the URI of another database and still getting the same error.

Comment: I came across this issue today, and realised I had an '@' in the password - which doesn't play nice with the '@' denoting the end of the user/password field. I just changed the password to remove it. It worked!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that `URI.parse(<DATABASE_DAVILA_URL here>)` succeeds. Chances are you have non-url safe characters in your database username/password. You will need to`URI.encode` them.

Comment: I've tried this in the ruby console:

`uri = URI.parse(<URI>)
uri.user
uri.password`

etc

they all work